# Dynamic JQuery toggle dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, toggle

I have some divs inside a table, just to get a fine setup.
When i press a div, a text drops down under it, and if you press the div again, the text gets away again.

also, when i press one of the divs, a img to the left, will show an arrow down, and when its normal, it will show an arrow pointing right.

I have this function on 10 divs.

My problem is, when i press div 1, it workes fine, the arrow shows down, and the text drops down.. BUT when i, for example press another div, when the first is open, the arrows starts to mess up..

is there a way here to make it dynamic ??

Heres my JQ :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var tjek = "TRUE";
    $(".title").click(function()
    {                                                                                      
        $(this).children('.subtitle').toggle(500);
        if(tjek == "TRUE")
        {
            $(this).css({"background-image" : "url('/images/images/Pil_open.png')"});
            tjek = "FALSE";
        }else{
            $(this).css({"background-image" : "url('/images/images/Pil_normal.png')"});
            tjek = "TRUE";
        }
    });
});
```

And heres the HTML:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" style="min-height: 100px; width: 698px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top">                                                                                                                                    
<div class="title">
    <p id="tekst">
        <b>BLA BLA BLA</b>
    </p>
    <div class="subtitle">
        TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
    <div>
</div>
</td>
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `toggleClass`.

```
$(".title").click(function() {

    var $element = $(this);

    $element.toggleClass('open');
    $element.children('.subtitle').toggle(500);
});
```

Css

```
.title {
    background-image: url('/images/images/Pil_normal.png');
}

.title.open {
    background-image: url('/images/images/Pil_open.png');
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GVYZm/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to do this all day, and couldn't find a way. It works like a charm

Comment: can you help me once more ? If i want all the other divs to close, when a new div is selected to be viewed, how can i do this ? I've tried $("subtitle").hide(); but it doesn't change the arrow ofc, but cant see how i can mix them together